# Translation of academic papers from Japanese?

Tags: mathematics, statistics, translations, japan

I am a Japanese translator and (amateur) math autodidact.

For practice and learning, I want to start translating Japanese academic papers into English, especially those related to mathematics or statistics.

My question:

- Is there demand for such papers to be translated (volunteer or otherwise)?

Any guidance on where to start or whom to contact would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The American Mathematical Society's publishing arm puts out the series [Translations of Mathematical Monographs](http://bookstore.ams.org/MMONO). A significant portion of the series (for reasons beyond me) are translations from *Japanese* language originals. Getting in touch with the editors of that series may be a good place to get started.